# Java application crash when uses icepdf library

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface, jvm-crash, icepdf

In my application I use the library icepdf. when you create a class of applications is broken and creates a log file. Help in solving problems

Log file:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d034bee, pid=3304, tid=3364
#
# JRE version: 6.0_21-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (17.0-b17 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [awt.dll+0x34bee]
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x03168c00):  JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3364, stack(0x00d70000,0x00e70000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0xe1ecbd40

Registers:
EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x00000018, ECX=0x000000cc, EDX=0x00000000
ESP=0x00e6f54c, EBP=0x00000000, ESI=0xe1ecbd40, EDI=0x23a5ff74
EIP=0x6d034bee, EFLAGS=0x00010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00e6f54c)
0x00e6f54c:   00e6f5a8 00000018 00e6f62c 00000014
0x00e6f55c:   6d0ab541 00cccccc 00000000 00000018
0x00e6f56c:   00000014 23a60164 000003a0 00000000
0x00e6f57c:   00000000 00000018 03081760 00000100
0x00e6f58c:   0015f660 00000400 e1ecbd40 00000000
0x00e6f59c:   00000000 00000018 00000014 00000000
0x00e6f5ac:   00000000 00000018 00000014 00000000
0x00e6f5bc:   00000000 00000004 00000400 00000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x6d034bee)
0x6d034bde:   00 0f b6 84 01 40 35 10 6d 0b ea c1 e5 08 0b e8
0x6d034bee:   89 2e 47 83 c6 04 4b 75 99 8b 54 24 18 8b 4c 24 


Stack: [0x00d70000,0x00e70000],  sp=0x00e6f54c,  free space=3fd00e6f080k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [awt.dll+0x34bee]

[error occurred during error reporting (printing native stack), id 0xc0000005]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop()V+0
j  sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run()V+52
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x042c9c00 JavaThread "Image Fetcher 2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=388, stack(0x04430000,0x04480000)]
  0x03153400 JavaThread "Image Fetcher 1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=584, stack(0x03810000,0x03860000)]
  0x0312e400 JavaThread "Image Fetcher 0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4088, stack(0x00390000,0x003e0000)]
  0x03526800 JavaThread "D3D Screen Updater" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2128, stack(0x04970000,0x049c0000)]
  0x0356f400 JavaThread "SwingWorker-pool-3-thread-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2196, stack(0x04920000,0x04970000)]
  0x0356d800 JavaThread "SwingWorker-pool-3-thread-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=468, stack(0x048d0000,0x04920000)]
  0x03522000 JavaThread "SwingWorker-pool-3-thread-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2796, stack(0x04880000,0x048d0000)]
  0x03521800 JavaThread "SwingWorker-pool-3-thread-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=996, stack(0x04740000,0x04790000)]
  0x0315f400 JavaThread "SwingWorker-pool-3-thread-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2136, stack(0x04830000,0x04880000)]
  0x0415c400 JavaThread "SwingWorker-pool-3-thread-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2112, stack(0x047e0000,0x04830000)]
  0x03598400 JavaThread "SwingWorker-pool-3-thread-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2132, stack(0x04790000,0x047e0000)]
  0x04109400 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3980, stack(0x04520000,0x04570000)]
  0x0364a000 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-1" [_thread_blocked, id=4056, stack(0x03f40000,0x03f90000)]
  0x03567800 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=4064, stack(0x03bc0000,0x03c10000)]
  0x03537400 JavaThread "Keep-Alive-Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4044, stack(0x03b70000,0x03bc0000)]
  0x0352c400 JavaThread "CacheCleanUpThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4448, stack(0x038b0000,0x03900000)]
  0x0352a800 JavaThread "CacheMemoryCleanUpThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3884, stack(0x03860000,0x038b0000)]
  0x00c38400 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=3284, stack(0x00cd0000,0x00d20000)]
  0x0316a800 JavaThread "Javaws Secure Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3168, stack(0x037c0000,0x03810000)]
=>0x03168c00 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3364, stack(0x00d70000,0x00e70000)]
  0x03167800 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=3880, stack(0x03770000,0x037c0000)]
  0x03166800 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3876, stack(0x03720000,0x03770000)]
  0x03103400 JavaThread "traceMsgQueueThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3732, stack(0x03460000,0x034b0000)]
  0x030e3800 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3720, stack(0x033a0000,0x033f0000)]
  0x030e0800 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3728, stack(0x03350000,0x033a0000)]
  0x030db800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3788, stack(0x03300000,0x03350000)]
  0x030da400 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3716, stack(0x032b0000,0x03300000)]
  0x0308f000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3708, stack(0x03260000,0x032b0000)]
  0x0308d800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3704, stack(0x03210000,0x03260000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0308c000 VMThread [stack: 0x031c0000,0x03210000] [id=3712]
  0x030ee000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x033f0000,0x03440000] [id=3724]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 17536K, used 3452K [0x22970000, 0x23c70000, 0x27ec0000)
  eden space 15616K,   9% used [0x22970000, 0x22aef070, 0x238b0000)
  from space 1920K, 100% used [0x238b0000, 0x23a90000, 0x23a90000)
  to   space 1920K,   0% used [0x23a90000, 0x23a90000, 0x23c70000)
 tenured generation   total 38756K, used 28076K [0x27ec0000, 0x2a499000, 0x32970000)
   the space 38756K,  72% used [0x27ec0000, 0x29a2b0e8, 0x29a2b200, 0x2a499000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12800K, used 12791K [0x32970000, 0x335f0000, 0x36970000)
   the space 12800K,  99% used [0x32970000, 0x335edd40, 0x335ede00, 0x335f0000)
    ro space 10240K,  51% used [0x36970000, 0x36e9b700, 0x36e9b800, 0x37370000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x37370000, 0x37a076c0, 0x37a07800, 0x37f70000)

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00424000  C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe
0x7c900000 - 0x7c9b1000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
0x7c800000 - 0x7c8f6000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
0x77dc0000 - 0x77e6c000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x77e70000 - 0x77f01000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x77d30000 - 0x77dc0000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
0x77f10000 - 0x77f56000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
0x77fe0000 - 0x77ff1000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\Secur32.dll
0x71a90000 - 0x71aa7000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\ws2_32.dll
0x77c00000 - 0x77c58000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x71a80000 - 0x71a88000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2HELP.dll
0x71ab0000 - 0x71aba000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000  C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\msvcr71.dll
0x6d800000 - 0x6daa7000  C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x76b20000 - 0x76b4e000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
0x6d7b0000 - 0x6d7bc000  C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\verify.dll
0x6d330000 - 0x6d34f000  C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.dll
0x6d000000 - 0x6d14a000  C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\awt.dll
0x72fc0000 - 0x72fe6000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x76360000 - 0x7637d000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.dll
0x774d0000 - 0x7760c000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
0x773c0000 - 0x774c2000  C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.2600.2180_x-ww_a84f1ff9\COMCTL32.dll
0x77f60000 - 0x77fd6000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x6d290000 - 0x6d298000  C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\hpi.dll
0x4fd70000 - 0x4ff16000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\d3d9.dll
0x6df20000 - 0x6df26000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\d3d8thk.dll
0x77bf0000 - 0x77bf8000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\VERSION.dll
0x76be0000 - 0x76beb000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d7f0000 - 0x6d7ff000  C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\zip.dll
0x746e0000 - 0x7472b000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x6d1d0000 - 0x6d1e3000  C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\deploy.dll
0x77a70000 - 0x77b05000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x77b10000 - 0x77b22000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x7c9c0000 - 0x7d1d8000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x77110000 - 0x7719c000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x771a0000 - 0x77246000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\WININET.dll
0x77250000 - 0x772f0000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\urlmon.dll
0x6d610000 - 0x6d623000  C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\net.dll
0x6d630000 - 0x6d639000  C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\nio.dll
0x6d6b0000 - 0x6d6f6000  C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\regutils.dll
0x71a30000 - 0x71a70000  C:\WINDOWS\System32\mswsock.dll
0x76f10000 - 0x76f37000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x76fa0000 - 0x76fa8000  C:\WINDOWS\System32\winrnr.dll
0x76f50000 - 0x76f7d000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\WLDAP32.dll
0x76fb0000 - 0x76fb6000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x10000000 - 0x10015000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRWEBSP.DLL
0x039a0000 - 0x039c3000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\nvappfilter.dll
0x698b0000 - 0x69908000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\hnetcfg.dll
0x71a70000 - 0x71a78000  C:\WINDOWS\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x76fc0000 - 0x7703f000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\CLBCATQ.DLL
0x77040000 - 0x77107000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\COMRes.dll
0x03c70000 - 0x03f3d000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\xpsp2res.dll
0x75e60000 - 0x75f10000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\SXS.DLL
0x0ffd0000 - 0x0fff8000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x769a0000 - 0x76a54000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\USERENV.dll
0x5bd50000 - 0x5bda4000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\netapi32.dll
0x6d230000 - 0x6d284000  C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x6d790000 - 0x6d798000  C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\sunmscapi.dll
0x4ebe0000 - 0x4ed83000  C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.GdiPlus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.0.2600.2180_x-ww_522f9f82\gdiplus.dll
0x6d1a0000 - 0x6d1c3000  C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\dcpr.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\plugin.jar -Djava.security.policy=file:C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\security\javaws.policy -DtrustProxy=true -Xverify:remote -Djnlpx.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin -Dsun.awt.warmup=true -Djnlpx.origFilenameArg=http://proxyapp.doci.in.ua/med/registry/jnlp/_jnlpWogNuL.jnlp -Djnlpx.remove=false -Djnlpx.splashport=1426 -Djnlpx.jvm=C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe 
java_command: com.sun.javaws.Main http://proxyapp.doci.in.ua/med/registry/jnlp/_jnlpWogNuL.jnlp
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\Program Files\PHP\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;"C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin"
USERNAME=user
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 15 Model 75 Stepping 2, AuthenticAMD



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows XP Build 2600 Service Pack 2

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 15 model 75 stepping 2, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, mmxext, 3dnow, 3dnowext

Memory: 4k page, physical 2062764k(1217788k free), swap 4001232k(3294388k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (17.0-b17) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_21-b07), built on Jul 17 2010 01:10:15 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

time: Sat Aug 28 13:37:31 2010
elapsed time: 24 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

From the snippet you pasted,its a segmentation fault (ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0xe1ecbd40) because sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop() function tried to write some contents to the memory address 0xe1ecbd40,which is either protected,or lies in kernel memory region, or inaccessible. This is why it crashed. This segfault is happening in sun AWT library awt.dll. Because eventLoop() should be calling some native function which in turn causing this segfault.So its not a problem with your application,its a crash within class library of JDK. Further analysis of this issue requires debugging of the postmortem logs.You are already on the latest JDK level,so it looks to be new issue within class library library. I think if you can open a ticket with SUN,then they might be able to look into it and can help you.Meanwhile you can try with some older version of JDK,it might be possible that some new code changes in the recent version might be causing this issue,but its just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much to go on from the dump but you could try the following system property encase it's Direct3D issue.

`-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false`